# Does this sentence "I fixed her a chair." make sense?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence.
*I fixed her a chair."
I want to know whether this sentence makes sense or not?
Please, give me your answer.

Comment: You should explain what has prompted you to ask this question. *Why* do you think something might be wrong. Otherwise this question could be closed as being "proofreading", and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Another problem is the request, if you ask "Does it make sense" well I would honestly reply it does, I understand what the speaker is saying without any problem. But does it sound odd? Or  can it be improved? Then the answer is "yes". And a more open type of question would be: "How would a native speaker write or say this phrase?

Comment: Do you know what the situation was? Was there a usable chair available? If so, perhaps the person "got her a chair"

Comment: Sure.  It means you provided her a chair.  Or "fixed her up", "fixed her up with".  Perhaps she came to dinner, and all chairs at the table were occupied by other diners, so you brought an extra chair for her.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider *fixed him a chair* old-fashioned or dialectical; it would be unusual to hear in contemporary standard English, but I wouldn't call it "incorrect" per se.

I'm supposing you encountered this phrase in Mark Twain's 1896 *[Tom Sawyer, Detective](https://archive.org/stream/PdfBooksAndWorksSubmittedByAceH.W/TomSawyerDetectiveByMarkTwain_djvu.txt)*:

> … and here HE was too, and a privileged character, on accounts of his being deef and dumb and a stranger, and they had fixed him a chair inside the railing, where he could cross his legs and be comfortable, whilst the other people was all in a jam so they couldn't hardly breathe.

The whole work is written in highly colloquial English, mimicking the vernacular of small-town Missouri; *couldn't hardly*, for that matter, would be also be unacceptable in standard English, as a double negative, but would be perfectly ordinary in this dialect and register.

Here, *[fix](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fix)* is used in the sense of preparation [AHD]:

> **fix**, *v. tr.* 2.a. To make ready for a specific purpose, as by altering or combining elements; prepare:
>
> > fixed the room for the guests; fix lunch for the kids.

Instead of *fix him a chair*, I might say *prepare him a chair*, *reserve him a chair*, *assign him a chair*, and so on depending on the precise activity involved.

I found only a few similar examples online, all from literature and none from journalism:

> Philip fixed her a seat under the willow, arranged her dinner, and brought her water from the brook, and she enjoyed it all lazily and thoroughly [*[Peterson Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=B8M6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347)*, 1866]
>
> Miss Eliza fixed him a place to sleep on a couch beside Colonel Hinds' bed [*[Mississippi Secrets](https://books.google.com/books?id=pq_YK6AqPZEC&lpg=PA95&ots=n93k7lM-xe&dq=%22fixed%20him%20a%20place%22&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=%22fixed%20him%20a%20place%22&f=false)* by Gary D McDowell, 2007]
>
> Martha fished a blanket out of the trailer and fixed her a spot where she could sit [*[La Hacienda Rancho Grande](https://books.google.com/books?id=EPn2ANJ8m54C&lpg=PA221&ots=MXqBGQWFzQ&dq=%22fixed%20her%20a%20spot%22&pg=PA221#v=onepage&q=%22fixed%20her%20a%20spot%22&f=false) by Beatrice E. Toppins, 2008]

Answer (score 0):

No.

In parts of the USA, "to fix her a (something)" means "to prepare a (something) for her," but it's almost always used to describe food: "I fixed a sandwich for her." This expression comes from an older meaning of "to fix."

When something is *actually* "fixed," as in "repaired," you would always say "I fixed the chair for her." You didn't *prepare* the chair, and you certainly didn't *cook* it, you *fixed* it.

To summarize: the usage of "fix" you describe is only appropriate when using "fix" as a synonym for "prepare" or "acquire," which is only widely appropriate in the context of food, and only in certain regions (it would sound out of character for, e.g., a New Yorker).

Answer (score 0):

A "fix", when not referring to performing repairs, is a quick effort to provide a solution to satisfy a need.

If you are in the woods, without much of any tools to perform elaborate carpentry, and all you have are branches and tree stumps - and your beloved girlfriend needs a chair and you accomplished that with a tree stump, some branches and leaves - that is a fix. Then indeed, you did "fix" her a chair.

If you had managed to find pieces of an Ikea knocked-down quick-assemble chair, and you fixed her a chair within a few minutes, without elaborate efforts, without spending time planing, sanding, polishing, etc, then indeed you "fixed" her a chair.

But if she has an existent chair that is broken, you would "fix her chair", rather than "fix her a chair".

Let's say that it would normally take 2 years to build a star ship and the year is 5012. Han Solo came visiting and his star ship got totaled and had to be discarded. And then Chewbacca pilfered scraps from the junk yard and fixed up a star ship within two weeks - then we could say that Chewbacca had "fixed" Han Solo a star ship.

However, if Han's star ship had simply needed extensive repairs, then we would say that Chewbacca had "fixed Han's star ship" rather than "fix Han a star ship".